# Origins of »nets«

Tags: meaning, etymology

I wonder what the etymological origin of the English word "net" was (German "Netz") and what it originally referred to? Had it initially to do with and orginated from fishermen's nets? Or what else had been originally named by predecessors of "net" and "Netz"?

And what about Latin "rete"? Are "net" and "rete" etymologically connected - and what did "rete" initially mean?

Comment: Just some links: https://www.etymonline.com/word/net#etymonline_v_6877 https://www.etymonline.com/word/rete#etymonline_v_37183

Comment: I have never doubted that "net", as in "local area network", arises from a woven net.  A "network", when graphed, looks like a fishnet.  Consider that the global network is called the "World-Wide Web".  Of course, "net", as used in accounting does derive from the Latin/Italian/French word for "glitter"

Comment: One remark before the question is closed (unfortunately): I intend to ask - in a completely different context - the question "What can be caught by neural nets?" And knowing that "net" initially meant "fishnet" would make this question even more meaningful.

Comment: I think you're reading more into "neural net" than is there.  The neural net is patterned like a net, with cross-links between neurons (whether real or computerized).  It's not about catching things.

Comment: @HotLicks: No, it's not that I am reading too much into "neural nets", it's just playing with words: Neuroscience trys to capture (= catch) a lot of phenomena - and to explain them - by referring to the neural network of the brain. My question is: How far can neuroscience succeed?

Comment: @Hans-PeterStricker - That's not a question for this group.

Comment: @HotLicks: Of course, not *this* one - as only asked in my last comment. But the original one should fit - it's just about etymology (even though too "trivial" or whatever?). Do you guess why it is voted to close?

Comment: @Hans-PeterStricker - Please include the research you’ve done, or consider if your question suits our English Language Learners site better. Questions that can be answered using commonly-available references are off-topic.

Comment: Hint:  Google `etymology net`.